# how to append string on C++

Tags: c++, mfc

when it calls function, the latest string left only 
ex) first call "abc" second call "def"
best result is "abc"\n"def" , actual result : "def"

visual 6.0 C++

```
void PrintCSV(CArchive &archiveContent, CStringList &strList, CString szSeparator)
{
    if( strList.IsEmpty() )
        return;

    CString strOneRecord;
    POSITION posTail = strList.GetTailPosition();
    POSITION pos;

    for( pos = strList.GetHeadPosition(); pos != posTail; )
    {
        CString str = strList.GetNext( pos );
        strOneRecord += str;
        strOneRecord += szSeparator;
        strOneRecord += "\t";
    }

    strOneRecord += strList.GetNext(posTail);
    strOneRecord += _T("\r\n"); // windows change a line
    archiveContent.WriteString(strOneRecord);
}
```

ex) first call `"abc"` and second call `"def"`

Expected result is `"abc\r\ndef"`

Actual result : `"def"`

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correctly appending one string to another string.

The problem is that you overwrite the old file. You must open the file with `CFile::modeNoTruncate` and go to the end of the file:

```
CFile file;
if (file.Open(filename, CFile::modeWrite | CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeNoTruncate))
{
    file.SeekToEnd();

    CArchive ar(&file, CArchive::store);
    PrintCSV(ar, strList, szSeparator);
}
```

You can also obtain a handle to `CArchive`'s `CFile` and go to end of file:

```
ar.GetFile()->SeekToEnd();
```

---

Note that `CArchive` is commonly used for serialization. If you are not doing serialization then skip `CArchive`. Use `CFile` directly, or use `CStdioFile` as follows:

```
CStdioFile file;
if(file.Open(filename, 
    CFile::typeBinary | CFile::modeWrite | CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeNoTruncate))
{
    file.SeekToEnd();
    file.WriteString(str);
    file.Close();
}
```

(add `CFile::typeBinary` for `CStdioFile` if you are handling `"\r\n"` yourself)